# How do I backup all the photos I have in Picasa 3 to Amazon S3?

Tags: picasa, amazon-s3

I have thousands of photos that I would like to push to Amazon S3.  Picasa has them all indexed, but they are spread all over my computer and a USB drive.

How do I backup all the photos I have in Picasa 3 to Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some tool like [Webdrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html) to map Amazon S3 to a local drive letter on your computer, and then get Picassa to store the photos in that mapped drive letter. Then your files are stored on S3, plus locally if you turn on the local mirroring feature in Webdrive.

I personally just get Picassa to use a Dropbox folder as it's photo folder, and then I have the photos locally, plus on Amazon (via Dropbox!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [minio client](http://minio.io/#mc) aka mc. Using [mc mirror] command you can mirror your local directory with your S3 bucket.

mc implements the following commands

```
  ls        List files and folders.
  mb        Make a bucket or folder.
  cat       Display contents of a file.
  pipe      Write contents of stdin to one or more targets. When no target is specified, it writes to stdout.
  share     Generate URL for sharing.
  cp        Copy one or more objects to a target.
  mirror    Mirror folders recursively from a single source to many destinations.
  diff      Compute differences between two folders.
  rm        Remove file or bucket [WARNING: Use with care].
  access    Manage bucket access permissions.
  session   Manage saved sessions of cp and mirror operations.
  config    Manage configuration file.
  update    Check for a new software update.
  version   Print version.
```

Hope it helps.